# R (glm.nb) Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long

Tags: r, statistics, glm

I have species abundance count data

[image]

Negative binomial is the best fit for my data so I'm trying to run a glm.nb as follows:

```
glmabundance2021 <- glm.nb(cbind(Abundance2021,Abundance2022)~Treatment, data=`macariasignaria`)
```

It runs fine with just 1 response variable (no cbind) but when I try to run this it gives me the following error:

```
Error in x[good, , drop = FALSE] : (subscript) logical subscript too long
```

So I can run them separately just fine but not as one.
Any help? I'm new to r.

Tried to run >

```
glmabundance2021<-glm.nb(cbind(Abundance2021,Abundance2022)~Treatment, data=`macariasignaria`)
```

but getting errors.

Comment: Welcome to SO. You maximize your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimal reproducible example. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  may help.

Comment: Can you please post this snippet of your data as text (e.g. using `dput()` or just columnar text in a code block) rather than as an image?

Answer (score 0):

The model formula you have here specifies a *multivariate* negative binomial model, i.e. multiple responses for each row of the data. `glm.nb` doesn't do that

You might get away with converting your data to long format, example as follows:

```r
dd <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
treatment year1 year2
A         1     3
A         2     4
A         7     2
B         1     4
B         2     5"
)
```

[Convert data to long format](https://www.statology.org/stack-columns-in-r/) (or use `tidyr::pivot_longer()`):

```r
dd2 <- cbind(treatment = dd[,"treatment"], 
     stack(dd, c("year1", "year2"), drop = FALSE))
```

```r
MASS::glm.nb(values ~ ind*treatment, dd2)
```

(this gives some warnings because the variation in the tiny fake data set is too small to distinguish from a Poisson model ...)

Alternatively, if each row represents a site or species, you might need to fit a *mixed-effect* model that adds a variable that identifies the original row each value came from ...

```r
dd2$subj <- rep(1:5, 2)
lme4:::glmer.nb(values ~ ind*treatment + (1|subj), dd2)
glmmTMB::glmmTMB(values ~ ind*treatment + (1|subj), dd2)
```

(These two models are supposed to give the same answer. They actually give different answers in this case, again probably because the data are tiny and fake ...)